# Exponents with variables inside exponents

Tags: exponentiation

I am confused about how to reduce this, is there any way?

$\sqrt x \ln(\sqrt x) = ln(\sqrt x^\sqrt x) = $ $?$

This can be written like this too:

$ln(x^\frac{x^\frac{1}{2}}{2}$)

Or:

$ln(x^\frac{\sqrt x}{2}$)

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{x}\ln (\sqrt{x})=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\ln x$$
If you need to simplify it more, please comment.

Comment: I realize your answer is a better way to simplify it, but is there a way to simplify this:
$\sqrt x^\sqrt x$
Just curious

Comment: You can only write it as: $x^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Ok, thanks. If x represents a big equation, it would be nice to reduce it to one x variable.

Comment: @JeremiahBarrar $$\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}}=\exp\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\ln x\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $\ln{(\sqrt{x})}=\frac{1}{2}\ln{x}$ so:

$\sqrt x \ln(\sqrt x) = 1/2 \sqrt{x} \ln{x}$